# What's the quickest way to gather gmail email data for a php web app?

Tags: php, api, gmail

I'm looking at the gmail api's and I'm not sure which one will allow me access to user's email  data with the least amount of coding effort.

I've never used zend or google's oauth features - this makes learning the OAuth access to IMAP and SMTP options somewhat time consuming.  I'm considering the atom feed, but I'm not using this with a reader/aggregator, (using a custom filter webapp), so I'm not sure which one to use.

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you planning on downloading an entire inbox for offline viewing, searching an inbox for certain incoming/outgoing mail, or something else? Do you require reading the entire, fully downloaded inbox/messages of the user - or simply the subject lines to/from etc?

Comment: entire body of the email - I'm searching for specific string instances in the email bodies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is already logged in, you can parse an ATOM feed of their inbox. https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/

Info here: http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/docs/

Comment: I've looked into this, but I can't find a wait to view the entire body of emails.  I also cannot receive access to read mail.  There's very little documentation for the atom feed on that page.